# How to calculate a recursive Function

Tags: computer-science, recursion

Let $f(x)$ be defined as $f(5x/4)$. Let $x = 6$. The result should be $2$. How would I calculate this?

This equation arose while developing a game. Let's say you have a conveyor belt and you want to separate the items equally between $3$ lines. However, you only have a machine that separates them into $2$ lines equally. So you take one machine and on each of the $2$ out puts you put another machine, making $4$ equally separated lines. Than you take one of the lines and feed it back into the main line. When you have $6$ items per second, this should result in a result of $3$ lines with a total of 2 items per second. The Actual equations would be $f(x)=f(x + x/4)$. Hope this picture helps for visualization.

Edit: I don't think my function is right, because it tends to infinity.

I think it should be f(x)=x + f(x/4). And I think this should be an infinite sequence which should be convergent.

Edit: I think the infinite serize x + x/4 + x/16 + x/64 + x/256 ...

f(x)=x times the sum of 1/(4^i) where i = 1 and i goes to infinity. The infinite sum converges at 1/3. Meaning f(x) = x/3. If you use Wolfram Alpha, this is their syntax. Sum[Divide[1,Power[4,i]],{i,1,∞}]

[image: Image of conveyor belt]

Comment: what are you trying to ask?

Comment: I don't know how to solve the function, it would be equivalent to a recursive function in computer science without a end condition. You get a stack over flow.

Comment: would you just have to compute the function until the result is equal to the input?

Comment: You need to take 2 more items here and use your procedure that will give 4 pairs of 2 and then return the 2

Comment: But think of the case when you start, where you only have six items coming in. The result is all of them equaling 1.5 and that gets feed back into the input, now you have 7.5 which result's in 6 + 1.875. ect.

Comment: @okzoomer I think that is the answer. How do you calculate a geometric series like that? honestly I had confirmation bias, I was looking at something the converged at 1/3, and I only tried adding the first 3 or 4 terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{in}(t_n)=6+\frac14 {\text{out}(t_n)}\\
\text{out}(t_n)=\text{in}(t_{n-1})$$

Asume that the limits exist and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{in}(t_n)=\text{in}_0$$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{out}(t_n)=\text{out}_0$$
then you have
$$\text{in}_0=6+\frac14 {\text{out}_0}\\
\text{out}_0=\text{in}_0$$
and from this
$$\implies \text{in}_0=6+\frac14 {\text{in}_0}\implies \text{in}_0=8$$
and $$\frac14 \text{out}_0=2$$

The sequence $$ \text{in}(t_n)$$ is increasing and bounded by $8$, so it must be convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have an input rate of $x_i$ and the rate of items getting looped back through is $x_l.$ The total input rate into the system which divides into four conveyor belts is $x_i + x_l,$ so each conveyor belt will have a rate of $\frac{x_i + x_l}{4}.$ Then the rate of the loop will become the rate of one conveyor belt, so $x_l \leftarrow \frac{x_i + x_l}{4}.$

Equilibrium will occur when $x_l$ continuously gets the same value, so when $\frac{x_i + x_l}{4} = x_l,$ implying $x_l = \frac13 x_i.$ If $x_l$ starts below $\frac13 x_i,$ then $\frac{x_i}{4} > \frac{3x_l}{4}$ implies that $\frac{x_l + x_i}{4} > x_l,$ and similarly if $x_l$ starts out above $\frac13 x_i$ we obtain $\frac{x_i + x_l}{4} < x_l.$

This means that over time the system should naturally fall into a stable equilibrium where $x_l = \frac13x_i,$ which will lead to each output stream having $\frac13$ of the input as you desired.

Comment: Is this another way to come to the solution i did without the infinite serize?

Comment: @JonathanArendt in general steady state problems can be solved with markhov chains. It's just that with the symmetry and relative low difficulty of the problem, you could do it using just one equation instead of a system of equations.

Comment: @JonathanArendt I suppose so, yes. The main reason I might say I prefer this is that the infinite series reasoning only really lets you know what happens when you start out with nothing in the loop, whereas this gives a bit better assurance of the stability of the equilibrium, at least that's how I see it.

Comment: @StephenDonovan See what I wanted to know is the process from 0 to equilibrium, Does this actually show that it will reach equilibrium or just that it is in equilibrium?

Comment: @okzoomer So basically i made a markhov chains which was overly complicated for such a simple system. (that is so much like me to do....)

Comment: @JonathanArendt This shows that it should reach a near-equilibrium state, because at any point where the amount in the loop is less than the equilibrium, the amount which gets fed into the loop next will be increased, so the amount will grow and approach the equilibrium condition.

Comment: @StephenDonovan That makes a lot since and is really useful. I was so intrigued at the idea of a recursive function and didn't look for the simple answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your equation is difficult to "solve" is just that you have mixed two different quantities up and called both $x$. Let's call $x$ the total number of items externally entering the system per unit time, and let's call $y$ the number of items actually entering your splitters per unit time. Then the correct equation analogous to the one you have written down is just that (in the steady state) $y = x + \frac{y}{4}$, essentially as you have observed.

This equation is easy to solve for $y$; we get $y = \frac{4}{3} x$. This is fine: it just says that no matter the number $x$ of items entering the system per unit time, we'll always have $\frac{y}{4} = \frac{1}{3} x$ i.e. $\frac{1}{3}$ of that rate of items circling back in the one of the four channels which feeds back into the inputs. (This is assuming that $x$ is constant and we are in the steady state.)

Everything still works out and the conveyor belts don't get clogged up because we can calculate that the number of items leaving the 3 remaining belts per unit time is (as you have said) just $\frac{3}{4} y = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{3} x = x$, i.e. per unit time the same number of items leave the system as enter.

Comment: I feel like that fails to stand when you initially only have the 6 items coming in. before it reaches equilibrium.

Comment: @JonathanArendt Sure, as I said this analysis is only at equilibrium. However, it is impossible for us to give you non-equilibrium time evolution equations because these will be a bit yuck, depending on the total amount of time it takes for an item to do a loop through the conveyor which loops back on itself.

Comment: if you look at the recursive equation and start to draw it out. it results in this ugly fraction. once simplified down, you see the infinite searize I noted above. Then i realized it could be condense down into an infinite sum. Which if you took at in step to infinity you would get the numbers for that many revolutions around the track.